# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied

Tags: python, mysql

This is a usual problem i've encountered before:

```
:~$ mysql -h "1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" -u "someuser" -ppassword "somepass" -D "somedatabase"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'someuser'@'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' (using password: YES)
```

But this time, when I try to connect to the remote vps `xxx.xxx.xxx....`. 
I get an error 1045 where the ip address is my ip address which tells me its clearly not even trying to connect to the remote vps.
(xxx is not yyy. i want to connect to the xxx.x...)

Any guesses, help? anyone else faced such problem before?

i tried the same thing from python via mysql connector module but same thing.

Comment: `xxx` is the server's IP, and `yyy` is your IP. Its telling you that access for `someuser` from IP `yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy` is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow access to the user from remote locations.

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'remotehost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'remotehost';
FLUSH PIVILEGES;
```

Comment: The second line is the absolute *worse* thing you can do, for a remote user no less!

Comment: Agreed, but I do not know the privileges/schemas/tables he needs.

Comment: @EliteTech You mean there's no access issues from my local machine right? If so, then GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * => what is the first field for and second after the dot. I can fill in the table name then. user@remotehost would be dbusername or my linux usrname @ my ip address?

Comment: the first asterisk is the schema or database, then the second asterisk is the table. Yes, the remotehost is your ip address of your client. For better security look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges to restrict non needed privileges.